# Traefik 2 does not match 2 Entrypoints

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, reverse-proxy, traefik

i have simple question. I want to receive a response from the backend on two different ports. According to the documentation, this should be a simple task. I did so, but for some reason one part does not work. What am I missing?

http://my-service.com -> **Works.**

http://my-service.com:6666 -> **Does not work.**

I configured traefik:

Static-conf:

```
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
  websecure:
    address: :443
  traefik:
    address: :9000
  web2:
    address: :6666
```

Dynamic-conf:

```
http:
  routers:
    StartPage:
      entryPoints:
        - web
        - web2
      service: MyService
      rule: "Host(`my-service.com`)"

  services:
    MyService:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://ca-service-svc.app/"
```

Traefik dashboard does not show any errors. I see my configuration.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you determine that is does not work? what is the error message? in which environment do you run this setup?

Comment: @Thomas - thank for rhe answer. Environments - Kubernetes Deployment. Provider -> File. Simple message: This site can’t be reached. In developer-console I do not see the response code. It just does not load.

Comment: Where is your kubernetes running, how do you try to access the port? Can you show the curl output?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it. The problem was at port 6666 and nginx. I did not know, that is one of reserved ports by nginx. I changed the port and everything works, as expected.